# Can I use dispatch group not in a loop?

Tags: swift, asynchronous, swift3, grand-central-dispatch

Say I have 3 different asynchronous tasks I want to get done before calling some function. I'm aware of using dispatch groups to do such a thing if those tasks were in a loop,

```
    var dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

    for task in tasks {
        dispatchGroup.enter()

        DoSomeTask { (error, ref) -> Void in
            dispatchGroup.leave()
        }
    }

    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main, execute: {
        DoSomeFunction()
    })
```

However, I'm confused on how you'd do this if those tasks were all in the same function but didn't have to do with eachother, like pushing 3 different values to your database. Something like this:

```
   updateDatabase() {
        var dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

        DoTask1 { (error, ref) -> Void in           
        }

        DoTask2 { (error, ref) -> Void in           
        }

        DoTask3 { (error, ref) -> Void in        
        }
   }
```

Where would you put the `leave` and `enter` statement in such a case as this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case your `updateDatabase()` function needs a completion block that you call after all update are done:

```
updateDatabase(onSccess completion:() -> Void) {
    var dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

    dispatchGroup.enter()
    DoTask1 { (error, ref) -> Void in   
        dispatchGroup.leave()        
    }

    dispatchGroup.enter()
    DoTask2 { (error, ref) -> Void in           
        dispatchGroup.leave()
    }

    dispatchGroup.enter()
    DoTask3 { (error, ref) -> Void in        
        dispatchGroup.leave()
    }

    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
        completion()
    }
}
```

You than call it like this:

```
updateDatabase() {
    //do somthing after updating
}
```